# GroovyConsole Adding dependent jars

Tags: groovy, dependency-management, groovy-console

I am running GroovyConsole on a mac (to launch I just do groovyConsole from the command line). I am a newbie so not sure how I can import needed libraries (jars). For example suppose my groovy script needs apache commons httpclient.

Do I need to specify the jar names in the command line when I open groovyConsole or should I be using Grapes? If it is the latter, I am not sure, the exact syntax of the Grab command. I tried the below and it didn't work...

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab('org.apache:commons-httpclient:3.1'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)])

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do just

```
 @Grab('org.apache:commons-httpclient:3.1')
```

Or you can add jars from the menu in the groovy console itself

Comment: I am sorry Tim but if I put just that one line in GroovyConsole, I get an error saying "java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.apache#commons-httpclient;3.1: not found]"